# How do I delete the awkward empty space under icon in TabBar in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm using `TabBar` in `AppShell` to create a tab. Like the code below, it is very simple but the problem is that I just want to put the icon and the icon should automatically be vertically centered but instead, there is an awkward space under the icons.

```xml
<TabBar>
    <Tab Icon="home.svg">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Icon="plus.svg">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AddDareTextPage}" Route="AddDareTextPage"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Icon="profile.svg">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="MainPage"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

[image: awkward space under each icon]

As you can see with the above picture the icons are not vertically centered and it upwards a little bit. I didn't know what caused this because in the code, there is nothing that sets the location of the icon but then I realized it was the space for the `Title`.

This is when I added `<Tab Icon="home.svg" Title="MAIN">` in the code so there is a title under one icon. And as you can see in the image below, the unnecessary space is gone.

[image: the unnecessary space is gone]

Is there a way to just put the icons and center them vertically? I don't want to put any `Title` in `TabBar` but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: I'm guessing the target is Android?

Comment: This is an android only issue correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the [Using Custom Renderers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) in .NET MAUI to remove the extra space and get the icon vertically centered.

At the moment the title has a fix height so there is an empty space under the icon. We need use the [Using Custom Renderers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI) to set the `bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;` to remove the extra space occupied by title and get the icon vertically centered.

Here are the detailed steps listed below:

1.Create a custom ShellRenderer class in the `Platforms/Android/` directory of your application:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility; 
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility;

namespace MauiApp2;

class CustomShellHandler : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new Platforms.Android.CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(this, shellItem.CurrentItem);
    }

}
```

2. To customize BottomNavView create a new class CustomBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker in the same directory：

```
using Android.Graphics.Drawables; 
using Android.Views;
using Google.Android.Material.BottomNavigation;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;

namespace MauiApp2.Platforms.Android
{

    class CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : ShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        private readonly IShellContext shellContext;

        public CustomShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext, ShellItem shellItem) : base(shellContext, shellItem)
        {
            this.shellContext = shellContext;
        }

        public override void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            base.SetAppearance(bottomView, appearance);
         

            // the key is to set like below
            bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;


        }

    }

}
```

3. The final step is registering our handlers in `MauiProgram.cs` like below:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder(); 
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
#if ANDROID
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellHandler));
#endif
 })
```

**Running output**:

[image]